# DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient doesn't work on inline elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have some navigation elements constructed like so

```
  <div id="topnavcontainer">

              <a href='/web/link1.html' >link1</a>
              <a href='/web/link2.html' >link2</a>
              <a href='/web/link3.html' class='current'>link3</a>

  </div>
```

The CSS for `#topnavcontainer a.current` specifies a gradient and uses `DXImageTransform` so that IE can render the gradient too.

It does, however, only seem to work if I set `#topnavcontainer a.current` to `display: block` which ruins the way the navigation works.

Does anyone know any work arounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: for filters to work, your element must [have layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html). There are a number of ways to do this via CSS (outlined in the linked document). One way (which is not valid CSS but will work) is

```
zoom: 1;
```

Another that is valid CSS but may affect formatting. is

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Would embedding the links inside a list give it "layout" and solve the issue?

Comment: @Chris: No, it has to be the element itself that has layout.